# BASH: Assigning MySQL SELECT result elements to different variables

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

Perhaps I am overcomplicating but ,I'm have built the following statement:

```
query="SELECT url, users FROM result as r INNER JOIN search as s ON s.UID = r.SearchID WHERE s.isProcessed = 0
```

The next step is to loop though the result but I need to be able to call urls and users separately. That's how I am attempting it:

```
while read -r link users; do
    output+=("$link", "$users")
done < <(mysql -h $host -u $user -p$pwd -s -N -D $db  -e "$query")

for i in ${!output[@]} ; do
    echo "${output[i]}"
```

Any hint how to echo users only, please? 
The above will return both urls and users :(

Comment: Why are you putting them both in the same array? Make one array of links, and another array of users.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't put commas in bash arrays. It's not a delimiter, it's being put on the end of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users are in the odd-numbered elements of `$output`, so start at 1 and increment the array index by 2.

```
for ((i=1; i < ${#output[@]}; i+=2)); do
    echo "${output[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Is it possible to solve this with simple if statement? Something like this    if [ i%2=1 ]; then
    echo "${output[i]}";
   fi

Comment: You need to use an arithmetic expression: `if (( i % 2 == 1))`

Comment: Thank you for you help. I can see this is working form me.